# chrome and javascript: onclick issues

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i am on a pc using javascript and chrome. the issue is the following

    `<a href="#" onClick="classClick(event,1)"`
This is not working in chrome, but is working perfeclty in FF. I tried "onChange" as was recommended by some results on a search, but still no luck. Any hints?

Comment: The syntax you show is fine in Chrome as it is in any other browser. The problem is most likely in the `classClick()` function. Do you get any errors in Chrome? (Press Ctrl+Shift+J to open the console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly isn't working and what are you trying to do?

I just tested this on chrome and it worked

```
<a href="#" onClick="alert('flag')">Flag Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for answering the question, i did not pose it in the way i intended. this is for legacy if anyone stumbles upon this question.

this code works for translating an event in FF,IE, and Chrome on PC.
i will edit later for Mac compatibility if need be for safari.

```
<span onclick="multiBrowserEventHandling(event)">Trigger</span>
<script>
function multiBrowserEventHandling(e){
     if(e.srcElement==undefined){
          e=e.originalTarget.innerHTML;
     }else{
          e=e.srcElement.innerHTML;
     }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may because the translate function name is a **reserved word** to google chrome extensions.

For instance the function name '**translate()**' cannot be used in chrome unless refering to the real translate.google.com service.